# Xquery / Xpath what is the meaning of /*:

Tags: xpath, xquery

Xquery / Xpath what is the meaning of /*:

(: Here $patterns looks like `<pattern match="something" replace="else" />` :)

```
declare function local:transform($text as text(), $patterns as element(pattern)*) {
   if(not($patterns)) then 
      $text
   else
      let $patternsremaining := $patterns[position() > 1],
          $modifiedtext := replace($text, $pattern/@match, $pattern/@replace)
      return 
         if($local:language="French" and not($patterns[@match='le'])) then (
             local:transform($modifiedtext, ($patternsremaining, <pattern match="Londres" replace="London" />))
      )
      else(
         local:transform($modifiedtext, $patternsremaining)
      )
};
```

Comment: It is a child of the root node. But what does it has to do with the source you posted? There is no /*

Comment: @BeniBela The markup engine hid it.  I've editted the question to expose it.

Comment: @Ross Patterson: Looks like the /* simply isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
```

**is an XPath expression that selects all element children of the root (document) node**.

It is equivalent to:

```
/child::*
```

As any well-formed XML document must have exactly one top element (child of the document node), the above two expressions select exactly one element -- the top element of the XML document.